# How to rank value within each row in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to make a rank for values within each row in pandas, so how to do it?
The data is as below:

```
   a            b            c          
0.000121    -0.000034   -0.000455   
-0.000265   -0.000007   -0.000009
```

The desired result is as below:

```
   a            b            c         a_rank        b_rank       c_rank          
0.000121    -0.000034   -0.000455         1            2            3
-0.000265   -0.000007   -0.000009         3            1            2
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html) with parameters `axis=1` and `ascending=False`, add [`DataFrame.add_suffix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html) for chnage columns names and last [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original:

```
df = df.join(df.rank(axis=1, ascending=False).astype(int).add_suffix('_rank'))
print (df)
          a         b         c  a_rank  b_rank  c_rank
0  0.000121 -0.000034 -0.000455       1       2       3
1 -0.000265 -0.000007 -0.000009       3       1       2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html) over `axis=1` with [`DataFrame.add_suffix`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html):

```
df = pd.concat([df, df.rank(axis=1, ascending=False).add_suffix('_rank').astype(int)], axis=1)

          a         b         c  a_rank  b_rank  c_rank
0  0.000121 -0.000034 -0.000455       1       2       3
1 -0.000265 -0.000007 -0.000009       3       1       2
```